# Let $f(x) = x + 2\sin(\ln(\frac{1}{x}))$ for $x \geq 1$. Show that $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq 3|x-y|$ for all $x, y \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

**My attempt:**

$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert x-y + 2(\sin(\ln(\frac{1}{x})) - \sin(\ln(\frac{1}{y}))) \rvert$$

Using triangle inequality and $\lvert \sin(x) - \sin(y) \rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert$ we have:

$$\lvert f(x) -f(y)\rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert + 2\lvert \ln(\frac{1}{x}) - \ln(\frac{1}{y})\rvert$$

I'm stuck here. I know that for $0 < x, y \leq 1$ we have $\lvert x - y \rvert \leq \lvert \ln{x} - \ln{y} \rvert$ but it's the opposite of what I want. Am I missing something obvious? Or do I need a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\geqslant1$, you have $f(x)=x+2\sin\bigl(-\log(x)\bigr)$ and therefore$$f'(x)=1-\frac{2 \cos (\log (x))}x.$$So,$$|f'(x)|\leqslant1+\frac2{|x|}\leqslant3$$and therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem,$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant3|x-y|.$$

Comment: Nice, clean solution. It's obvious now that I see it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.